# Face detection in background in Android

Tags: android, service, background, face-detection

I am trying to develop a sample face detection application in Android for my thesis. I have tried with the FaceDetecor class which is available in the Android SDK itself and it works fine. But i want to make it run in background. Because i want to make an app that makes a sound or something whenever the user stare at his phone and walking fast or running. So i need the face detection in background. I make it run as a service but whenever i close the app the thread is still running but the face detection stops because the preview stops

Check the thread where i capture the picture...
Here is my code...thank you in advance

```
public final class FaceDetectRGBActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback 


{

public static final String TAG = FaceDetectRGBActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int MAX_FACE = 10;
private final CameraErrorCallback mErrorCallback = new CameraErrorCallback();
long start, end;
int counter = 0;
double fps;
private int numberOfCameras;
private Camera mCamera;
private int cameraId = 1;
private int mDisplayRotation;
private int mDisplayOrientation;
private int previewWidth;
private int previewHeight;
private SurfaceView mView;
private FaceOverlayView mFaceView;
private boolean isThreadWorking = false;
private Handler handler;
private FaceDetectTask detectTask = null;
private int prevSettingWidth;
private int prevSettingHeight;
private android.media.FaceDetector fdet;
private FaceResult faces[];
private FaceResult faces_previous[];
private int Id = 0;
private String BUNDLE_CAMERA_ID = "camera";
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> facesCount = new HashMap<>();

private float speed;
private accelerator ac= new accelerator();;
private StepCounter steps=new StepCounter();;

private ArrayList<Bitmap> facesBitmap;

/**
 * Initializes the UI and initiates the creation of a face detector.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_viewer);

    mView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // Now create the OverlayView:
    mFaceView = new FaceOverlayView(this);
    addContentView(mFaceView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    // Create and Start the OrientationListener:


    handler = new Handler();
    faces = new FaceResult[MAX_FACE];
    faces_previous = new FaceResult[MAX_FACE];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FACE; i++) {
        faces[i] = new FaceResult();
        faces_previous[i] = new FaceResult();
    }


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Face Detect RGB");

    if (icicle != null)
        cameraId = icicle.getInt(BUNDLE_CAMERA_ID, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check for the camera permission before accessing the camera.  If the
    // permission is not granted yet, request permission.
    SurfaceHolder holder = mView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_camera, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;

        case R.id.switchCam:

            if (numberOfCameras == 1) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Switch Camera").setMessage("Your device have one camera").setNeutralButton("Close", null);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                return true;
            }

            cameraId = (cameraId + 1) % numberOfCameras;
            recreate();

            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Restarts the camera.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    startPreview();
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(BUNDLE_CAMERA_ID, cameraId);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    //Find the total number of cameras available
    numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            if (cameraId == 0) cameraId = i;
        }
    }

    mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);

    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        mFaceView.setFront(true);
    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mView.getHolder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not preview the image.", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // We have no surface, return immediately:
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
       // return;
    }



    try {
       // mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore...
    }

    configureCamera(width, height);
    setDisplayOrientation();
    setErrorCallback();

    // Create media.FaceDetector
    float aspect = (float) previewHeight / (float) previewWidth;
    fdet = new android.media.FaceDetector(prevSettingWidth, (int) (prevSettingWidth * aspect), MAX_FACE);


    // Everything is configured! Finally start the camera preview again:
    startPreview();
}

private void setErrorCallback() {
    mCamera.setErrorCallback(mErrorCallback);
}

private void setDisplayOrientation() {
    // Now set the display orientation:
    mDisplayRotation = Util.getDisplayRotation(FaceDetectRGBActivity.this);
    mDisplayOrientation = Util.getDisplayOrientation(mDisplayRotation, cameraId);

    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);

    if (mFaceView != null) {
        mFaceView.setDisplayOrientation(mDisplayOrientation);
    }
}

private void configureCamera(int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    // Set the PreviewSize and AutoFocus:
    setOptimalPreviewSize(parameters, width, height);
    setAutoFocus(parameters);
    // And set the parameters:
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}

private void setOptimalPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters cameraParameters, int width, int height) {
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    float targetRatio = (float) width / height;
    Camera.Size previewSize = Util.getOptimalPreviewSize(this, previewSizes, targetRatio);
    previewWidth = previewSize.width;
    previewHeight = previewSize.height;

    Log.e(TAG, "previewWidth" + previewWidth);
    Log.e(TAG, "previewHeight" + previewHeight);

    /**
     * Calculate size to scale full frame bitmap to smaller bitmap
     * Detect face in scaled bitmap have high performance than full bitmap.
     * The smaller image size -> detect faster, but distance to detect face shorter,
     * so calculate the size follow your purpose
     */
    if (previewWidth / 4 > 360) {
        prevSettingWidth = 360;
        prevSettingHeight = 270;
    } else if (previewWidth / 4 > 320) {
        prevSettingWidth = 320;
        prevSettingHeight = 240;
    } else if (previewWidth / 4 > 240) {
        prevSettingWidth = 240;
        prevSettingHeight = 160;
    } else {
        prevSettingWidth = 160;
        prevSettingHeight = 120;
    }

    cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);

    mFaceView.setPreviewWidth(previewWidth);
    mFaceView.setPreviewHeight(previewHeight);
}

private void setAutoFocus(Camera.Parameters cameraParameters) {
    List<String> focusModes = cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE))
        cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
}

private void startPreview() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        //isThreadWorking = false;
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        counter = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
    mCamera.setErrorCallback(null);
    mCamera.release();
    // mCamera = null;
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
    if (!isThreadWorking) {
        if (counter == 0)
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        isThreadWorking = true;
        waitForFdetThreadComplete();

        detectTask = new FaceDetectTask(handler, this);
        detectTask.execute(_data);

    }

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

             isCameraUsebyApp();

            Log.e("Hello", "HELLO");
            if (detectTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                Log.e("ALIVE", "ALIVE");

            } else Log.e("DEAD", "DEAD");


        }
    }, 0, 1000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
}

public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (camera != null) camera.release();
    }
    return false;
}

private void waitForFdetThreadComplete() {
    if (detectTask == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (detectTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {

        detectTask = null;

    }

}



private class FaceDetectTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Integer, String> {
    private Handler handler;
    private byte[] data = null;
    private Context ctx;
    private Bitmap faceCroped;

    public FaceDetectTask(Handler handler, Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
        data = params[0];

        Log.e("FaceDetectThread", "running");

        float aspect = (float) previewHeight / (float) previewWidth;
        int w = prevSettingWidth;
        int h = (int) (prevSettingWidth * aspect);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21,
                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), null);above
        Rect rectImage = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());


        ByteArrayOutputStream baout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        if (!yuv.compressToJpeg(rectImage, 100, baout)) 
        {
            Log.e("CreateBitmap", "compressToJpeg failed");
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(baout.toByteArray()), null, bfo);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, false);

        float xScale = (float) previewWidth / (float) prevSettingWidth;
        float yScale = (float) previewHeight / (float) h;

        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotate = mDisplayOrientation;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT && mDisplayRotation % 180 == 0) {
            if (rotate + 180 > 360) {
                rotate = rotate - 180;
            } else
                rotate = rotate + 180;
        }

        switch (rotate) {
            case 90:
                bmp = ImageUtils.rotate(bmp, 90);
                xScale = (float) previewHeight / bmp.getWidth();
                yScale = (float) previewWidth / bmp.getHeight();
                break;
            case 180:
                bmp = ImageUtils.rotate(bmp, 180);
                break;
            case 270:
                bmp = ImageUtils.rotate(bmp, 270);
                xScale = (float) previewHeight / (float) h;
                yScale = (float) previewWidth / (float) prevSettingWidth;
                break;
        }


        android.media.FaceDetector.Face[] fullResults = new android.media.FaceDetector.Face[MAX_FACE];

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FACE; i++) {
            if (fullResults[i] == null) {
                faces[i].clear();
            } else {
                PointF mid = new PointF();
                fullResults[i].getMidPoint(mid);

                mid.x *= xScale;
                mid.y *= yScale;

                float eyesDis = fullResults[i].eyesDistance() * xScale;
                float confidence = fullResults[i].confidence();
                float pose = fullResults[i].pose(android.media.FaceDetector.Face.EULER_Y);
                int idFace = Id;

                Rect rect = new Rect(
                        (int) (mid.x - eyesDis * 1.20f),
                        (int) (mid.y - eyesDis * 0.55f),
                        (int) (mid.x + eyesDis * 1.20f),
                        (int) (mid.y + eyesDis * 1.85f));

                if (rect.height() * rect.width() > 100 * 100) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_FACE; j++) {
                        float eyesDisPre = faces_previous[j].eyesDistance();
                        PointF midPre = new PointF();
                        faces_previous[j].getMidPoint(midPre);

                        RectF rectCheck = new RectF(
                                (midPre.x - eyesDisPre * 1.5f),
                                (midPre.y - eyesDisPre * 1.15f),
                                (midPre.x + eyesDisPre * 1.5f),
                                (midPre.y + eyesDisPre * 1.85f));

                        if (rectCheck.contains(mid.x, mid.y) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - faces_previous[j].getTime()) < 1000) {
                            idFace = faces_previous[j].getId();
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    if (idFace == Id) Id++;

                    faces[i].setFace(idFace, mid, eyesDis, confidence, pose, System.currentTimeMillis());

                    faces_previous[i].set(faces[i].getId(), faces[i].getMidEye(), faces[i].eyesDistance(), faces[i].getConfidence(), faces[i].getPose(), faces[i].getTime());

                    if (facesCount.get(idFace) == null) {
                        facesCount.put(idFace, 0);

                        Log.d("Photo Taken!!", "PHOTO");
                        Log.e("Photo Taken!!", "PHOTO");


                    } else {
                        int count = facesCount.get(idFace) + 1;
                        if (count <= 5) {

                            Log.e("Photo Taken!!", "PHOTO");
                            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                            Log.e("Photo Taken!!", "PHOTO");


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("Hello there", "Hi");

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //send face to FaceView to draw rect
                mFaceView.setFaces(faces);

                //calculate FPS
                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                counter++;
                double time = (double) (end - start) / 1000;
                if (time != 0)
                    fps = counter / time;

                mFaceView.setFPS(fps);

                if (counter == (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000))
                    counter = 0;

                isThreadWorking = false;
            }
        };

        thread.start();



        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

}